# cuda nsight: generating debug symbolics: -G0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nsight

I have downloaded and installed CUDA 6.5 on windows 7 with visual studio 2010.

Let us say I build a sample CUDA code from SDK (visual studio 2010).

How do I know which compiler I am using?

Also how do I make sure that the CUDA Toolkit that I am using to compile my CUDA C
code must support the following switch for generating debug symbolics: -G0

This is mentioned [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/using_cuda_debugger.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%2520Tools%7CDesktop%2520Developer%2520Tools%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%25204.1%7CCUDA%2520Debugger%7C_____2) and quoted below:

> CUDA Toolkit: In order to use a project with the NVIDIA Nsight tools,
>   we recommend that you use the compiler that ships with the tools. The
>   default installation directory for this version of the compiler is:
>
> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA
>
> The compiler is in a subdirectory labeled by its version, such as:
>   ...\\bin\nvcc.exe
>
> The NVIDIA Nsight tools work best with this version of the compiler.
>   However, the tools also work with the standard toolkit. Whichever
>   compiler you use, the CUDA Toolkit that you use to compile your CUDA C
>   code must support the following switch for generating debug symbolics:
>   -G0

Answer (score 2):

The note that you are referencing is old and should be updated.

The Visual Studio C++ build system is extended to support CUDA by inclusion of a CUDA props file in the vcxproj. For example in the 6.5 samples you should find the sections

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CUDAPropsPath Condition="'$(CUDAPropsPath)'==''">$(VCTargetsPath)\BuildCustomizations</CUDAPropsPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
    <Import Project="$(CUDAPropsPath)\CUDA 6.5.props" />
</ImportGroup>

<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
    <Import Project="$(CUDAPropsPath)\CUDA 6.5.targets" />
</ImportGroup>
```

The default location for VCTargetsPath is

> c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0[VSver]\BuildCustomizations

If you open the "CUDA 6.5.props" file you can see how the location of the toolkit is determined.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Check CUDA Toolkit versioned environment variable. -->
    <CudaToolkitDir Condition="'$(CudaToolkitDir)' == ''">$(CUDA_PATH_V6_5)</CudaToolkitDir>

    <!-- Last, check the new CUDA Toolkit style/Nsight toolkit registry value. -->
    <CudaToolkitDir Condition="'$(CudaToolkitDir)' == ''">$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\GPU Computing Toolkit\Cuda\$(CudaToolkitVersion)', 'InstallDir', null, RegistryView.Registry64, RegistryView.Registry32))</CudaToolkitDir>

    <!-- Ensure $(CudaToolkitDir) has a trailing backslash. -->
    <CudaToolkitDir Condition="'$(CudaToolkitDir)' != '' AND !HasTrailingSlash('$(CudaToolkitDir)')">$(CudaToolkitDir)\</CudaToolkitDir>

    <CudaToolkitIncludeDir Condition="'$(CudaToolkitIncludeDir)' == ''">$(CudaToolkitDir)include</CudaToolkitIncludeDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Switching Toolkits in VXCPROJ**

In the vcxproj modify the version number in the CUDA .{props, targets} lines and reload the project.

**Switching Toolkits in VS**

In Visual Studio open Solution Explorer.
In Solution Explorer right click on the project node and execute "Build Customization"
In the Visual C++ Build Customization Files check the correct target.

**Overriding the Toolkit Location**

If you have a version of the CUDA toolkit that was not installed using the installer you can override the default locations by

a. Set the toolkit environment variable. For example, set CUDA_PATH_V6_5, or

b. Override the setting for CudaToolkitDir in the vcxproj, or

c. In VS in the  Property Page for the project change CUDA C/C++ | CUDA Toolkit Custom Dir.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable info.  As I am new in visual studio, I am still unable to understand. where do I see that -G0 option. Kindly modify your answer to include this point.